# How can i check if there is incoming data from a TCP Socket without receiving it?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Basically what i need to do is to get a notification, then proceed to receive the data using the class DataInputStream and the method read().

The problem is that the DataInputStream does not have a method to check if there is something to read and by doing tests with read() method would interfere with further calls to read().

I can do a hack to make the test by reading one byte and the append further data to it, but i would like to see if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DataInputStream` does not have a method to check if there is something to read

Yes it does. You missed the `available()` method, but it doesn't always return non-zero, depending on what you're connected to.

Have a look at `PushbackInputStream`.

Comment: You are completely right! I totally missed that, and it is the first method exaplained! I think i am tired. :) Thanks!